# How to get per sms price by passing "To" number via Twilio REST API?

Tags: api, rest, twilio

I am looking to get per sms rate by passing "To" mobile number for related country to display in my application, please suggest best solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately today we don't have a way via the API to find out the price of an SMS before sending it.  You can get the price of an individual message after its sent via the API by making a request to the Messages endpoint:

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages/{MessageSid}
```

We also publish a csv that contains all of our SMS pricing.  You can find that here:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/where-can-i-see-all-of-twilios-sms-pricing-in-one-place

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please keep this for future development records if some one want to add sms charge to client's order say for sms notification charges the app must be able to get the rate per sms according to the client's mobile number thanks for your help David, please let me know whenever you get any news in this regard :)

Comment: BTW i have been through the csv file showing all the pricing i am going to import this file to my app system and will update the app on regular intervals in case any price change, this will solve the problem for now, thanks again Devin sorry for typo mistake wrote Davide instead of Devin in my previous comment :p

Comment: Can't access csv file anymore can you please look into this thanks!!

Comment: Trying to see whats going on.  I'll let you know when I find out.

Comment: When you look at the .NET SDK  there are price and currency properties which are empty after you have submitted a message. I'm trying to get the price *after* I've pushed the message into Twilio (i.e. I think this is at the queued state) from the MessageResource Create reply. Does you answer still hold true in this case?

Comment: @DevinRader will the sent status callback have segments and price? I'm seeing null and 0 from the C# library response when creating a message.

Answer (score 1):

i was looking for a similar solution today and i had to code mind myself. Hope this gives you the idea. Though this method will cost you $0.005 per query.
If you can get another provider(s) to query a mobile number and get it's Mobile Network Code (MNC) then this solution becomes free.

```
<?php 
    $entry_number="+1239393939"; //The mobile num to query
    $account_sid = 'your twilio SID';
    $auth_token  = 'your auth token';

    // STEP 1, GETTING THE MNC(This costs $0.005)
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/'.$entry_number.'?Type=carrier',
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => ''.$account_sid.':'.$auth_token.'',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Number lookup'
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $array = json_decode($response);
    $country_code=$array->country_code;
    $mnc=$array->carrier->mobile_network_code;
    $network_name=$array->carrier->name;
```

// END OF STEP ONE, (You can var_dump($response); to see entire response

```
    // STEP 2, Checking the price (This step is free)
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://pricing.twilio.com/v1/Messaging/Countries/'.$country_code.'',
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => ''.$account_sid.':'.$auth_token.'',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Number lookup'
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $array = json_decode($response);
    $pricing= $array->outbound_sms_prices;
    foreach ($pricing as $data=>$value)
        {
                if ($value->mnc == $mnc){
            foreach ($value->prices as $data1=>$value1)
        {
        if ($value1->number_type == 'mobile'){
        $current_price=$value1->current_price;  // ECHO this line to show price             
       }
        }
        }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [code] => 20404
    [message] => The requested resource /PhoneNumbers/+1239393939 was not found
    [more_info] => https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404
    [status] => 404
)

This is the response array which I am getting on step 1. :(